# XSLT: filter out result except given list

Tags: xslt

I would like to filter out elements except some in a list.

I have this XML:

```
<catalog>
   <product>
      <code>Y17231</code>
      <pname>Test 1</pname>
   </product>
   <product>
      <code>Y19232</code>
      <pname>Test 2</pname>
   </product>
   <product>
      <code>Y18333</code>
      <pname>Test 3</pname>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

Currently I am filtering out all elements, which are not starting with Y19* code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product[not(matches(code, 'Y[^X]?19.*[^V]$'))]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is working, [xsltransform](http://xsltransform.net/bESZULm) example, example output:

```
<catalog>
   <product>
      <code>Y19232</code>
      <pname>Test 2</pname>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

**The goal:**

I would like to extend this with a feature, where I can define some codes, which are then not filtered out (they will be included in the result).

```
<xsl:param name="include-this" as="xs:string*" select="'Y18333','Y16222','Y12333'"/>
```

So output should be this:

```
<catalog>
   <product>
      <code>Y19232</code>
      <pname>Test 2</pname>
   </product>
   <product>
      <code>Y18333</code>
      <pname>Test 3</pname>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

Can you help me how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `match="product[not(code = $include-this) and not(matches(code, 'Y[^X]?19.*[^V]$'))]"`.

Comment: I want to use two functions together if possible. So first filter out elements based on `not(matches(code, 'Y[^X]?19.*[^V]$'))]"`, then include again with `product[not(code = $include-this)`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what `first` and `then` refers to in a single transformation.

Comment: I updated the example, I think it's now easily understable.

Comment: Doesn't my suggestion produce the wanted output? At http://xsltransform.net/bESZULm/2 it has the two `product` elements.

Comment: It works flawlessly, just tried. Thank you very much.